# Getting Error "Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running"

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I bought a Lumia 630 dual SIM recently and has been trying to register my phone for development, but kept getting this error "Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running".

What i use to register my phone is Windows Phone Developer Registration(8.1), and the method i have tried:

1. Restart IpOverUsbSvc service.
2. Restart phone, and turn off Set Automatic in date+time.

Any help on this will be highly appreciate as I have already spent 2-3 days trying to connect the phone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unplug the USB cable and try a different port, try also a different USB cable, and restarting the Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport service...

Take a look at [this](http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/28/problems-and-fixes-when-registering-a-windows-phone-8-device-to-deploydebug-applications/) thread....

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @anonshankar. I am able to connect my phone using another machine. Guess the problem is on the usb port.

Comment: Yeah because I faced the same issue :)

Comment: 0
down vote
I had to go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services

and start the

Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport Service.

My device is now working.

Comment: Replacing the cable solved it for me. The problematic one was longer than the one with which it is working. Interesting...both charge the phone, though...

Comment: In my case it was the cable. Changing cable fixed everything.

Answer (score 5):

I had to go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services

and start the

Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport Service.

My device is now working.

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the solutions proposed above, but was unable to get the tool to recognize the phone. The phone appeared in Explorer, but the registration tool just couldn't see it. Then I stumbled into this article:

http://toddbaginski.com/blog/fixing-windows-phone-developer-registration-tool-errors/

Basically, you go into Device Manager and uninstall all the USB composite devices. After Windows reinstall drivers for the phone, the registration tool should now be able to see it. It worked in my case, at least.

Answer (score 1):

**To uninstall a Windows Phone device**

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Double-click  in portable devices.
3. Right-click in windows phone, and then click Uninstall.
4. Click OK to complete the uninstall process.

**To reinstall Windows Phone device**

1. In Device Manager, in the Action menu, click Scan for hardware changes.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the windows phone device from ->Control Panel ->Hardware and Sound->Devices and Printers Options and again add it back.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, IpOverUsbSvc service was completely missing in the list of services.
I assumed it happened when I removed Windows phone support from Visual Studio 2015 and tried to debug app from VS 2013.
Repair of Visual Studio 2013 fixed the issue for me.
Hope that may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you try all of Kulasangar's tips and still don't have success, try a different USB cable. Despite the directions stating you must use the one that came with your Windows Phone, that didn't work for me. I took a 3rd party's cable in desperation and that worked immediately.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the below error message while developing app for Windows Phone.

Error Message:

> “Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.”

The cause of the error is that the service “Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)” is not running. It is very simple to resolve in error.

Simple header over to services.msc. Look for “Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)”, the status should be empty or automatic. Right click on it and select Start.

After doing that, try to deploy your app again and it should work fines.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem.

Solution
Apart from changing USB cable, restarting, we can do following steps:
1.Set the correct date and time 
2.Change the device name [ From your PC, you can simply change device name]
3.your device must have internet connection.