# Error "Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running”

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I bought a Nokia Lumia 520 and updated to 8.1, as it comes with only Windows 8 originally. After, I tried to register as a developer but I keep getting the same error status. I've tried switching from the USB cable that came with the phone to a third party, restarting the IpOverUsbSvc service, and even going into PowerShell to stop the service from there. I did get an error on Power shell that

start-service : Service 'Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) (IpOverUsbSvc)' cannot be started due to
the following error: Cannot open IpOverUsbSvc service on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service IpOverUsbSvc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: May this would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153897/getting-error-unable-to-connect-to-a-phone-make-sure-the-windows-phone-ip-over

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Francisco?

Comment: Chiming in @JamesMundy - I just am now dealing with this issue. Any luck?

Comment: @SMT yes I did but I am trying to remember exactly how. I think it had to do with the ipoverusb files missing from the location they were meant to be on my pc or something to do with the registry. Will try and see if I can remember....

Comment: @JamesMundy I got it working by swapping the USB cable after i posted actually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error "Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153897/getting-error-unable-to-connect-to-a-phone-make-sure-the-windows-phone-ip-over)